# System V "pg" command

Tags: command-line, software-installation, pager

I am an old System V guy, and I finally got around to setting up a Linux box, using Ubuntu, of course. One of the first things I noticed was missing is the "pg" command. The web tells me that it is available as part of the "util-linux" package. Ubuntu, which I loaded having checked the the boxes to "install everything," tells me that util-linux is installed, but "pg" and other scripting cammands  simply aren't there. Can this be fixed?

Comment: According to `apt-get changelog util-linux`, *util-linux (2.29.2-2) unstable; urgency=medium "The big post-release cleanup."* `* Stop shipping the deprecated 'pg' utility`.

Comment: Try to use the `more` or `less` command. Are there any special options in `pg` that do not have a counterpart in these commands?

Comment: Does it matter that I might just want it to give me comfort?

Comment: @ardevain well, if there's nothing particular in `pg` you need, `alias pg=less`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the package changelog (`apt-get changelog util-linux`) you will see that `pg` has been deprecated and removed:

> ```
> util-linux (2.29.2-2) unstable; urgency=medium
>
>   "The big post-release cleanup."
>
>   [ Andreas Henriksson ]
>   * Add DEP12 upstream metadata (Closes: #852731)
>   * Revert "Add configure flag to make libmount skip /etc/mtab"
>   * Drop explicit --disable-silent-rules configure flag
>   * Stop shipping the deprecated 'pg' utility
>   * Revert "Explicitly (re)enable deprecated pg utility"
>   * Stop shipping deprecated 'tunelp' utility
>   * Stop shipping the deprecated 'line' utility
>   * Drop explicitly passing CC for cross-building
>   * Use configure flags to disable utils shipped by bsdmainutils
>   * Revert "Attempt to work around debootstrap problems for hwclock.sh"
>   * Drop no longer needed lintian overrides for dropped workaround
>   * Drop obsolete fdisk reclaim on PPC
>   * Revert "Rename libuuid user to uuidd in libuuidd1 postinst as well"
>   * Revert "libuuid1: add passwd dependency for user migration"
>   * Drop obsolete uuid-runtime user/group migration code
>   * Remove 'pg' from being a pager alternative
>   * Stop shipping deprecated tailf utility
>   * Mention tailf removal in util-linux.NEWS</code></pre>
> ```

However the source code for `pg` is still present in the source package, so you can build and install it manually if you wish. You will need a suitable build environment such as provided by installing the `build-essential` package, plus relevant dependencies as provided by

```
sudo apt-get build-dep util-linux
```

First, make sure you have the `deb-src` type enabled for your `main` repository. Then you can download and patch the source in a directory of your choosing (unlike most `apt` operations, this doesn't need elevated privileges):

```
apt-get source util-linux
```

Change to the downloaded directory, and then configure the build to enable `pg`:

```
./configure --enable-pg
```

If it completes successfully,

```
make pg
```

Test it from the current directory using `./pg README` or the like.

Now instead of the usual "sudo make install" (which will attempt to build **all** the utilities), just copy the `pg` binary somewhere appropriate such as `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`

```
mkdir -p ~/bin && cp pg ~/bin/
```

If you choose `~/bin` and didn't previously have a `~/bin` directory, then it won't be added to your `PATH` until you start a new login shell or source the `~/.profile`:

```
. ~/.profile
```

so that you can execute `pg` from anywhere.

Alternatively, you could build ALL of the package with `--enable-pg`, then use `checkinstall` to install it in place of the Ubuntu provided package - however you will then be responsible for keeping it updated.